# How to configure a fast system with Ubuntu installed on a workstation for scientific computing

Tags: partitioning, ssd, performance, lvm, btrfs

I am in charge of a powerful workstation to support the scientific computing needs in our research center. We decided to run Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on the machine. However, I haven't done similar tasks for years. The last time I was managing a cluster/workstation was using CentOS in the old days. I am writing to ask your advice mainly for two things:

1. How should I configure the limited storage space for the best performance? The machine has performance-mismatched 512GB SSD + 2TB HDD. It may be expanded to have more PCIe-SSDs and HDDs in the future, and we will have 10-20 users to use the computer. Should I use [LVM](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm) for all partitions with `btrfs` filesystems for fast snapshotting? I think LVM and `btrfs` are good for future disk expansions with good performance but may increase the complexity of the system given that one `/home` or root directory could be spanned on both normal 2.5in SSD and faster PCIe m.2 SSDs.
2. What software is good for job submission management given that the machine has 28 cores currently with 1 GPU for CUDA (Matlab and such) and general purpose programming? We may install more GPUs in the future. It might be good to network with other computers as a mini cluster, but currently, we don't have the plan open yet.

Below is my initial plan to group the partitions, and I've heard [Slurm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slurm_Workload_Manager) is good for job queue management. PBS/TORQUE is also good for job queue management. Not sure which one is better for my case.

***512GB SSD (`/dev/sda`)***:

`/boot`, ext2, 250MB

`/swap`, LVM-SWAP, 10GB (32GB memory installed, to be upgraded with PCIe-NVM SSD cards later)

`/` (root), LVM-btrfs, 100GB (will be used to install a lot of shared software)

`/home`, LVM-btrfs, ~400GB

***2TB HDD (/dev/sdb)***:

`/backup`, LVM-btrfs, 1TB (we also have a remote backup disk server)

`/data`, LVM-btrfs, 1TB

At this stage, I am not sure about the backup strategy neither the file structure. Given the limited space of the SSD, we shrink `/home` to be only on SSD to give the current ~10 users enough space for programs and leave some space for future PCIe NVM SSD card expansions. So, if you have some thoughts on the other aspects of the workstation configuration, please don't hesitate to post.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you may need virtualization in some way look at Proxmox as it is a terrific VM management, provisioning, and orchestration system.   Proxmox supports user mgmt, network mgmt and cluster mgmt as well and there are both strong developer & user communities.

BTRFS or ZFS will give you snapshot/restore capabilities.  Each has its own Plus/Minuses.   BTRFS works great for my servers.. just don't use its Raid5 capability as its broken.  I use BTRFS Raid10.

Backups for such a large group of users & serious work should not be in the same physical machine.

Develop a security policy for users & network protection also.

Comment: I just searched Proxmox and feel it might be overkilling. On user management, I only care about how many cores a user can use and prioritize submitted jobs while not losing performance for computing. VM may take some overhead of resources. But good points on other aspects of your response! Thanks.